# Find the smallest integer parameter $a$ for which the following matrix is the Gram matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        13 & 5 & 1 \\
        5 & 2 & 2 \\
        1 & 2 & a \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I need find the smallest integer parameter $a$ for which the following matrix is the Gram matrix of a linearly independent system of vectors.

For the begining

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        13 & 5 & 1 \\
        5 & 2 & 2 \\   
        1 & 2 & a \\
        \end{vmatrix} \gt 0
$$
because The Gramian matrix is positive semidefinite.
From this condition, I brought that $a$ > 34.

What else should I take into account that this matrix is ​​the Gram matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** A matrix is Gramian if and only if it is positive semidefinite. And Gramian matrices arising from inner products of linearly independent vectors should be positive definite. So, what you have done is enough.

Comment: The requirement was for a linearly independent set of vectors. This precludes the semi part...

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, you're right. I've overlooked that bit.

Comment: I thought he wants the given matrix to be positive definite, how is that guaranteed by only the positive determinant condition

Comment: @dineshdileep The first two leading principal minors ($13$ and $1$) are positive and do not depend on $a$, so it remains to ensure that the determinant of the matrix is positive.

Comment: @user1551 ah yes, I see it. I thought you were talking in general